# How to tell Visio to make relevant (integral) constraints?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I found Visio is trying to constraint distances between elements, but doing this silly:

[image]

I.e. the proposed distance is neither integral number of units nor simple fraction of units.

How to teach Visio to behave well?

Answer (score 0):

Visio isn't constraining the distance, it's just aligning the shape you are dropping/moving with the grid. You can change the settings for this via the **Snap and Glue** and the **Ruler and Grid** dialogs.

Comment: Don't you see the grid on screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I can see it. Doesn't mean it's being used though.